# twitter image upload (twitpic api)- unable find image upload method

Tags: android, twitpic, android-twitter

I am new to android development. I need to post text and image in twitter through my Android application.

I got one sample project [AndroidTwitpic](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitpic). I had problem in connection. Later I replaced twitter4j-core-2.1.6.jar library with twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar library. Now the connection to Twitter is working fine but am getting error like:

> ImageUpload cannot be resolved to a type.

Is there any library required to add? What is the mistake I have done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add other libraries:

```
signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar
```

Comment: These libraries are for authentication and not for Media uploads.

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorail its very helpful [Twitt pic with text](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how things were placed prior to the Twitter4J 3.0.2 (I wasn't working on it then). However, somewhere in between versions, they seem to have changed the library (*speculation on my part*).

For uploading Media of any kind, you need an additional library called **twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3.jar**. You can download it here:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-media-support/3.0.3 (Choose the *Binary download* option on the page).

**Alternative Links:**

1. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core/3.0.3
2. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtwitter4jmediasupportjar.htm (Make sure you search for the latest version. It has a long list of earlier versions too)
3. http://twitter4j.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-media-support/3.0.3/